# How do I get one Dell PowerEdge R720 network interface up?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, dhcp, fedora, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell PowerEdge R720 and it only has one place in the back to plug in a network cable. But it has 5 possible network interfaces:

[picture of ip link show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbkjN.jpg)

But they are all DOWN when i run `ip link show`

I've tried adding a file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ for each interface, tried setting the IP manually vs using DHCP, but nothing seems to work.

I run `systemctl restart NetworkManager` when I make changes and I see in logs:

eno1 state change: unmanaged -> unavailable reason sys-iface-state: external

I know the network cable plugged in works, tried it on another computer. Any ideas what to try next? And how do I know which interface eno1, eno2, eno3, eno4, or enp0s26u1u2u4u4 is the right one?

Comment: ahh, thank you! I didn't look carefully enough. I found one place to plug it in and assumed that had to be it! But yes there are FOUR other places. Working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find the four Ethernet ports on the back directly below the black handle, between the USB ports and the power supply. They are numbered 1-4 and these should correspond exactly to the interface names `eno1` through `eno4`.

The port labeled iDRAC is for out of band management, and this is something you should set up separately.

My best guess about `enp0s26u1u2u4u4` is that it's the iDRAC's virtual NIC (again, you should set this up separately later).